# Why Axios in this code doesn’t send any data to the back-end in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to upload an image to the server with Vue js but it sounds like the Axios doesn't send any data to the back-end. The back-end is ASP.netCore API. It's very simple and I have made this form for submitting data to the server via fetch before and it works well!
Do you see anything wrong?
You can see my code below:

```
 <template>
    <h1>Uploading an Image!</h1>
    <p>This component demonstrates Uploading Image to server.</p>
    <div>
        <form>
            <input type="file" v-on:change="getFile($event)" />
            <button v-on:click="submitForm($event)">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {

        name: "Upload1",
        data() {
            return {
                selectedFile: " ",
                uploadResult: " "
            }
        },

        methods: {

            getFile(event) {
                this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
                console.log(this.file);
            },

            submitForm(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("ImageData.File", this.selectedFile);

                let config = {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                    }
                };
                axios.post('/api/Image', {

                    formData,
                    config

                }).then(resposne => resposne.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        
                        this.uploadResult = "File " + data.fileName + " successfully uploaded."
                    });
            }
        }

    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out to restructure the request like :

```
            event.preventDefault();
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("ImageData.File", this.selectedFile);

            let config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
            };
            axios({
                baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/', // your backend base url
                method: 'post',
                url:'/api/Image',
                data:formData,
                ...config

            }).then(resposne => resposne.json())
```

Comment: What is different between baseURL and URL here?

Comment: baseUrl is your backend base url like `127.0.0.1:8000/api` which common for all your urls, and the url is the appended part like `/users` or `/api/users`

Answer (score 0):

I was wrapping the formData and config in an object. They should be the second and third arguments passed to post, like this:

```
axios.post('/api/Image', formData, config)
```

And the problem is solved!